# How to emulate the clicked button with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form with two buttons.  In the controller, I detect which button is clicked and I do differents actions depending on the clicked button.

```
if ($editForm->getClickedButton() != null && 
    $editForm->getClickedButton()->getName()=='sauvegarder_suivant') {
```

This work great.

Problem is in some conditions, I ask the user to confirm if they really want to submit using a bootstrap modal window.  When the confirmation box is triggered, this break the button check in the controller.

```
$('form').submit(function (e)
{
  cible = e.target;
  e.preventDefault();

  // ...

  $('#ratio_confirmation').modal('show');

  $('#confirmer').on('click', function ()
  {
    cible.submit();
  });
});
```

I tried to permute the confirmation button and the real button id's and name's in the hope that symfony would catch the clicked button, but this is not working.

My plan B is to set the clicked button in an hidden field, but I would preferer using the getClickedButton way, if this is doable.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the requests:

with e.preventDefault()

```
form%5Bname%5D=1&form%5Bsurname%5D=2
```

without e.preventDefault()

```
form%5Bname%5D=1&form%5Bsurname%5D=2&form%5Bsecondsave%5D=
```

as You see, the button secondsave didn't pass with the form. You can do this
as example:

```
var $subbuttons = $(":submit");
$subbuttons.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $submitbutton = $(this);
    $('#ratio_confirmation').modal('show');
    $('#confirmer').on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).unbind('click');
        $submitbutton.unbind('click').click();
    });
})
```

This is bad example, but it works! :)
I think if you spend a little bit of time, You find out great solution !

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it works but you could try to explicitly check for the buttons from your formbuilder like

```
if ($form->get('save_and_add')->isClicked()) {
    // action 1
}elseif($form->get('save_and_add_other')->isClicked()){
   // action 2
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work.  It returns false. Probably the same issue that I have with getClickedButton().

Answer (score 0):

you can keep track of submit confirmation in a global variable like this.

```
var confirmedSubmit = false;

$('form').submit(function (e){
 if(!confirmedSubmit){
        $('#ratio_confirmation').modal('show');
        return false; 
 }
 return true;

});

$('#confirmer').on('click', function (){
    confirmedSubmit = true;
    $('form').submit();
});
```