# Display a confirmation on Click on a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, symfony

I have a form with several submit buttons. When I click on one, I want to display a confirmation, and if ok the form is submited :

So I have the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-button-confirm]', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var $this = $(this);

     alertify.confirm('Confirmation', $(this).data('button-confirm'),
         function () {
             $this.parents('form').submit();
         },
         function () {
             $(this).blur();
         }
     ).set('labels', {
         ok: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Confirm',
         cancel: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel'
     }).set('defaultFocus', 'cancel');
 });
```

But in my Symfony controller at the line of

```
if ($form->getClickedButton()->getName() === 'publish') {
```

I have the message

```
Call to a member function getName() on null
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem or a Symfony problem?

Comment: As you can see with the symfony message,  the jquery submit() function don't send the cliqued button, then the the form  bug. If someone have maded the same thing may be he could give me the tip

Comment: I don't know Symphony, but `$form->getClickedButton()->getName()` sounds like it assumes a button was used to submit the form, which is not the case: `$this.parents('form').submit();`

Comment: Exactly.  That's the reason I'm searchign for a workin way :)

Comment: @Lolo: Does the server-side code *need* to rely on the button's name and/or value?  Or could it look for some other data in the request?  For example, the JavaScript code could write to a hidden input before submitting the form.  What specifically does `getClickedButton()` do?

Comment: `getClickedButton()` : returns the button that was used to submit the form.

Comment: @Lolo: Does Symphony provide any documentation on specifically *how* it determines this?  If it's looking for a specific name and/or value in the posted data, for example?

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. If you already know that the name of the button is not sent, why not add it to the request? I would assume that this is not a problem of Symfony

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35727461/how-to-emulate-the-clicked-button-with-javascript helps? Or check how a common submission of your form differs from the submission done through jQuery

Comment: @NicoHaase I already tried to unbind the click( )event and call click(). The result is the form is not submited :(

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @NicoHaase, I found a way to resolve my problem.  I can't unbind the click event,then I remove the attribute `data-button-confirm` and it works.

I changed

```
 $this.parents('form').submit();
```

to

```
$this.removeAttr('data-button-confirm').click();
```

Thanx all for your help